# % Processor Time on Process vs. Proccesor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, performance, load-testing

I'm looking at a visual studio loadtest results, and something does not make sense.

The (_Total) % Processor Time under Process category is almost linear. 
The (_Total) % Processor Time under *Processsor* category makes saw teeth pattern.

**Question 1:** What is the difference between the % Prcessor Time under Process category vs. under Processor category?

When I look at the % Processor Time under a service process that I was running the load test against, it makes saw teeth pattern, so this looks related to the Processor category...not Process category?

**Question 2:** How come an individual process's % Process Time affects the Total % Process Time of the Processor, and not of the Process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. What is the difference between the % Prcessor Time under Process category vs. under Processor category?

   The best place to go for starting information on the perfmon stats is to run perfmon.exe. 
   From there

   - Process:

   > "The Process performance object consists of counters that monitor
   >   running application program and system processes.  All the threads in
   >   a process share the same address space and have access to the same
   >   data."

   - Processor:

   > "The Processor performance object consists of counters that measure
   >   aspects of processor activity. The processor is the part of the
   >   computer that performs arithmetic and logical computations, initiates
   >   operations on peripherals, and runs the threads of processes.  A
   >   computer can have multiple processors.  The processor object
   >   represents each processor as an instance of the object."

   This maps nicely to task manager information coming from the "Processes" tab (Processes) and compare that to the Performance tabs CPU Usage History (Processor).
2. How come an individual process's % Process Time affects the Total % Process Time of the Processor, and not of the Process?

   Essentially all the processes add up to the activity on the processors data. This is complicated by most machines having multiple processors and a multiple processes will utilise different processors depending on thier configuration.

   So individual Processes (applications) add load to your Processors (CPU's).

Comment: According to: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0435e7c5-3cda-41a0-953e-7fa462fde03b/perfmon-process-processor-time-vs-task-managers-cpu-usage-for-monitoring-a-specific-user?forum=perfmon you can estimate "Process (% CPU Time) <instance>" = "Process(%Processor Time)<instance>" / "number of processors" * "Processor(% User Time)<total>".

Comment: I still don't understand why (_Total) % Processor Time under Process category !=  (_Total) % Processor Time under Processsor category